# responsive charts with Plotly-Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

How can I make charts responsive? So that by changing the size of the browser or on any device, the size of the charts fits the size of the browser page? Thank you for your help

```
fig1= px.line(a,x=m,y=t1)
fig2= px.bar(a,x=m,y=t2)
app =dash.Dash(__name__,title='me')
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig1 ),
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig2)
    ], style={'display':'flex'}
    )])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key element here is the `responsive` parameter when creating the `dcc.Graph` objects. I let you check [the detailed documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph), but basically:

> If True, the Plotly.js plot will be fully responsive to window resize and parent element resize event.

Once you've set the responsivness to `True` you might want to play with the css flexbox attributes. IMO, the Code-Tricks [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is excellent to understand how it works.

You might want the following style to take the whole width space, properly resize, and wrap when the figures reach a minimal size.

```py
graph_style = {"flex": 1, "min-width": 700}  # Set the min-width you want
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig1, responsive=True, style=graph_style),
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig2, responsive=True, style=graph_style),
            ],
            style={"display": "flex", "flex-wrap": "wrap"},
        )
    ]
)
```

---

Here is a fully working example

```py
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, html, dcc

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")

fig_bar = px.bar(df, x="year", y="pop")
fig_line = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title="Life expectancy in Canada")

app = Dash(__name__)

graph_style = {"flex": 1, "min-width": 700}
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig_bar, responsive=True, style=graph_style),
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig_line, responsive=True, style=graph_style),
            ],
            style={"display": "flex", "flex-wrap": "wrap"},
        )
    ]
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```